# Ruby on Rails undefined method `each' for #<String:0x7efa908> Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to go through a string array in html, but get "undefined method `each' for #" error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqKlO.png)

Here is the class definition for Planet class

```
 class CreatePlanets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :planets do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :image, null: false
      t.string :description, array: true, default: '{}'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= @planet.name %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= @planet.name %></h1>
    <%= image_tag @planet.image %>
    <ul>
        <% @planet.description.each do |x| %>
        <li><%= x %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how I migrated it

```
p1 = Planet.create(name: "Sun", image: "/../assets/images/sun.jpg", description: ["The center of the solar system and the only star in solar system.", 
"Due to its huge mass, other planets in solar system form radiant power between sun and itself, maintaining the rotation around sun", 
"The surface temperature is said to be about 6000 degree celcius."])
```

At first, I tried default: [] in the class definition, but it fails, so I changed it to '{}'. If someone knows how to deal with this problem in either way, please let me know.

Thank you.

---

Edited:

After I tried @planet.description.lines.each, the output changes to this. [Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4sS9.png)

Which has the lists on the same line and also include the [] which should be the outer container of the array

---

Update:

Now I changed CreatePlanets class to

```
 class CreatePlanets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :planets do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :image, null: false
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My seeds.rb

```
p1 = Planet.create(name: "Sun", image: "/../assets/images/sun.jpg")
p1.description.push("The center of the solar system and the only star in solar system.", 
    "Due to its huge mass, other planets in solar system form radiant power between sun and itself, maintaining the rotation around sun", 
    "The surface temperature is said to be about 6000 degree celcius.")
p1.save
```

My Planet class

```
class Planet < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :description, Array
end
```

Comment: Which database are you using? AFAIK ActiveRecord only supports *PostgreSQL* array columns. Also, if it is an array then you might want to call it `descriptions`.

Comment: This is ActiveRecord as you can see in the first code block.

Comment: Yes but ActiveRecord on top of which database? ActiveRecord is a fairly thin layer over the database that doesn't really offer much in the way of portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails provides a way to create array type column, but ActiveRecord only supports PostgreSQL array columns, it won't work with mysql2 db so, i came across the same situation, and i did it by [serialize](http://thelazylog.com/using-serialize-option-in-ruby-on-rails/) column (By doing this you are independent of database dependency.)

1- Create a column of type `text` (or `db:rollback` if its last migration)

```
t.text :description
```

2- In `Planet` model

```
serialize :description, Array
```

3 -

```
p1 = Planet.new(name: "Sun", image: "/../assets/images/sun.jpg")

p1.description.push("The center of the solar system and the only star in solar system.", "Due to its huge mass, other planets in solar system form radiant power between sun and itself, maintaining the rotation around sun","The surface temperature is said to be about 6000 degree celcius.")

p1.save
```

4- Now you can go through each description , and it will treat as array instead of string

```
<%unless @planet.blank?%>
  <h1><%= @planet.name %></h1>
  <%= image_tag @planet.image %>
  <ul>
      <%unless @planet.description.blank?%>
        <% @planet.description.each do |x| %>
        <li><%= x %></li>
        <% end %>
      <%end%>
  </ul>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I tried the first 3 steps and when I tried to "seed" the database, I got 

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "{}"
C:/Sites/Planets/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: @Eric Did you change change column `description` as text only ? you can do it either revert migration or by creating new migration.

Comment: @Eric
`p1 = Planet.new(name: "Sun", image: "/../assets/images/sun.jpg")
p1.description.push("The center of the solar system and the only star in solar system.", "Due to its huge mass, other planets in solar system form radiant power between sun and itself, maintaining the rotation around sun","The surface temperature is said to be about 6000 degree celcius.")

p1.save`

Comment: I have updated my post, so you can see the information you need.

Comment: @Eric first line is p1 = `Planet.new(name: '...', image: '..')` its `new` not `create` and next line should be this, `p1.description.push("The center of the solar system and the only star in solar system.", "Due to its huge mass, other planets in solar system form radiant power between sun and itself, maintaining the rotation around sun","The surface temperature is said to be about 6000 degree celcius.")`
and then `p1.save` and i did it at my console, and it works fine.

Comment: @Eric so far as i can see error occurs at `C:/Sites/Planets/db/seeds.rb:9: ` which is at line number 9 in seed.rb is the line number 9 same that you have posted?

Comment: @Eric Are you still stuck? feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I went to bed and didn't see your response. For now, I am not really in trouble due to this issue, so let's just finish discussion on this. Thank you so much to take care of my problems and answer many of my cumbersome questions.